# How do I generate a Hexagonal grid in R

Tags: r, r-sp

I would like to be able to create a SpatialPolygons object (which is a Hexagonal grid) that covers another SpatialPolygon.

I would like all the Hexagons to have a diameter of 1km (ideally i can vary this) and for all the hexagons together to cover the whole object. The method below only seems to cover a small amount of it...

Below is my attempt using the `sp` package:

```
require(sp)
data(meuse.riv)
meuse.sr = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(meuse.riv)), "x")))
plot(meuse.sr)

HexPts <-spsample(meuse.sr,type="hexagonal",cellsize=1000)
HexPols <- HexPoints2SpatialPolygons(HexPts)
plot(HexPols, add=TRUE)
```

Any help as always is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

replace `meuse.sr` with some buffered version, like `rgeos::gBuffer(meuse.sr, width = 2000)` in the call to `spsample`. Here is a full example that selects only the intersecting hexagons:

```
require(sp)
data(meuse.riv)
meuse.sr = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(meuse.riv)), "x")))
plot(meuse.sr)

library(rgeos)
meuse.large = gBuffer(meuse.sr, width = 2000)
HexPts <-spsample(meuse.large, type="hexagonal", cellsize=1000)
HexPols <- HexPoints2SpatialPolygons(HexPts)
plot(HexPols[meuse.sr,], add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: I get this error: > HexPts <-spsample(rgeos::gBuffer(meuse.sr, 2000),type="hexagonal",cellsize=1000)
Error in spsample(rgeos::gBuffer(meuse.sr, 2000), type = "hexagonal",  : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'spsample': Error: is.logical(byid) is not TRUE

Comment: Thank you! That's very good...but How do I get it so that I only get polygons that intersect with the underlying spatial polygon, because at the moment with width=2000, there are some polygons that do not intersect with the underlying object at all...

Comment: added the full example to the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with `sf` without converting from and to `sp`?

Comment: There is also a nice post on the topic [here](http://strimas.com/spatial/hexagonal-grids/) by the way.

Comment: With `sf`, you can use `st_make_grid(x, square=FALSE)[x]` with `x = st_as_sf(meuse.sr)`