# Create non-overlapping Hexagons around point coordinates

Tags: r, raster, hexagonal-tiles

I have to create non-overlapping, irregular, hexagons (voronoi hexagons) around coordinate points. i found some answers to similar problems on SO and other places but i did not manage to adapt those solutions.

[how to draw tilegram/hexagon map in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707952/how-to-draw-tilegram-hexagon-map-in-r)

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273233/create-spatial-polygon-grid-from-spatial-points-in-r

[How do I generate a Hexagonal grid in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374004/how-do-i-generate-a-hexagonal-grid-in-r)

[Create hexagonal grid over city and associate with lon / lat points (in R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893734/create-hexagonal-grid-over-city-and-associate-with-lon-lat-points-in-r)

it is possible to do it just with sp, raster and rgdal as i have some partial data (see pic below) but i can't reproduce it.

The coordinates of the points come from an shp that looks like this:

```
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 148392 
extent      : -179.9844, 179.6227, 53.00372, 79.90965  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
variables   : 7
names       :   point, cell, grid,       lat,         lon,   cntr,         cont 
min values  : 2601723,  100, warp, 53.003719, -179.984421, Canada,       Arctic 
max values  : 3213512,  967, warp, 79.909653,  179.622711,    USA, NorthAmerica
```

dput sample here:

```
structure(list(point = c(3110786, 2861560, 2864634, 2864638, 
                         2864642, 2867700), cell = c("428", "282", "282", "282", "282", 
                                                     "282"), grid = c("warp", "warp", "warp", "warp", "warp", "warp"
                                                     ), lat = c(72.407028, 61.31004, 61.422215, 61.422215, 61.422215, 
                                                                61.534386), lon = c(-120.742577, -140.21254, -140.013031, -140.247162, 
                                                                                    -140.481308, -140.047607), cntr = c("Canada", "Canada", "Canada", 
                                                                                                                        "Canada", "Canada", "Canada"), cont = c("Arctic", "Arctic", "Arctic", 
                                                                                                                                                                "Arctic", "Arctic", "Arctic")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

the result should be an shp and look something like this:
[image]

the points are from the shp, only the hexagon structure is needed.